# ODBC in VBA slowly breaking

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, mysql-workbench

I am using Windows 7 Professional on a 64-bit Operating System. I am using VBA in Excel and a MySQL ODBC 5.2ANSI Driver connection in SysWOW64 to connect and run queries in a MySQL Workbench 6.3 database. My macro runs a series of queries. It was working fine until the other day when some of the queries stopped working. I print every query, and when I manually copy and paste the query into the MySQL Workbench database, the query runs fine; the data are definitely there. More and more queries have stopped working as time has gone on.

I.E. The first day with issues, a couple queries returned no results. The macro runs about 30 queries. Now, about 7 of the queries do not work.

I do not understand why some queries return results but not others. When I debug, I see the ADODB.Connection is connecting, but the record set is erroring out when attempting to run the query.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
Sub Test()

Dim myODBC As String

Dim ConnectionString As String

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String, SQL_ML As String
Dim Var as Double

ConnectionString = “Connection String”

SQL = “SQL String”
Var = MyFunction(SQL, ConnectionString)
    ‘ Different variable names are used within the function for the connection 
    'and record set
    ‘There are 4 functions in this fashion. Only 1 is erroring out at the 
     'moment!

Dim rng_ML As Range
Set rng_ML = Application.Range("rng_ML")
Dim ML_Matrix() As Double
ReDim ML_Matrix(1, rng_ML.Columns.count)

For i = 1 To UBound(ML_Matrix, 2)
    SQL_ML = SQL & rng_ML(1, i)
    Set rs = conn.Execute(SQL_ML)  ‘This is where it is SOMETIMES erroring out.
    rs.MoveFirst
    ws.Cells(Row, 1 + i).CopyFromRecordset rs
Next i
End Sub`
```

Again, this code has worked for months and is now slowly breaking. 
Has anyone heard of this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following check:

```
If rs.RecordCount > 0  Then
  rs.MoveFirst
  ws.Cells(Row, 1 + i).CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
```

I cannot see where you open the connection but I assume you do it before executing the SQL statements.
Please post the error description, otherwise we can just guess...

Comment: This is a good suggestion that I will use in the future. It ended up being unnecessary because the macro began working correctly again. I believe there was an issue with the database, even if IT does not want to admit it!